# How to put the Ajax call array(json) in to a global array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I'm very confiused right know! :)

I'm using the Ajax to get some date out of a mysql thru php.

The JS:

```
function toDb2(datastr,callback){
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: "config.php",
        data: datastr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(datax){
            if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") { 
                }
                alert(datax);
                callback();
            };
        }
    });
};
```

The PHP :

```
function hamtakl($valdaverktyg){
     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","r00t","");
     if (!$con)
     {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     mysql_select_db("toolpool", $con);
    $visahamtat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM level WHERE Verktyg='$valdaverktyg' OR Stang='ja' ORDER BY Datum");
    $p = array(); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($visahamtat))
      {
        $p[] = $row['Datum']; 
      }
      echo json_encode($p);
      mysql_close($con);
}
```

so far so good!
the output of ajax call looks like this:

```
 ["2012/11/26","2012/11/27","2012/11/05"]
```

I thouth everything is ok, but i need to put the "datax" in to a global array.
I tested

```
myglobalarray = datax ;
```

did not worked!
then I defined the array in the first line of my js like this:

```
var myglobalarray = new Array;
//allso tested  var myglobalarray = [];
```

but i dont know how to push the "datax" in to arrays now.
I think the problem is that the "datax" is not a array.

Basicly i need to get the dates and later on use them in jquery datepicker to disable the dates.
When I use datax = anotherGlobalVariable; and alert it out it's outputs

```
 ["2012/11/26","2012/11/27","2012/11/05"]
```

Now I'm lost! have no idea what I have to do :D!

Comment: Why do you assign `myglobalarray` to `datax` instead of the opposite?

Comment: Sounds like you just need `datax = JSON.parse(datax);` in the first line of the success function.

Comment: " data = $.parseJSON(datax);alert(data);" returns null

Comment: That's not what I suggested :s

Comment: datax = JSON.parse(datax);  = unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Comment: You're not returning data in a valid JSON format then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out

```
$.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
    url: "config.php",
    dataType:'json', // **please mention
    data: datastr,
    cache: false,
    success: function(datax){
        if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") { 
            }
            alert(datax);
            callback();
        };
    }
});
```

if you don't write `dataType:'json'` then it consider response as a string not a json object. :) Hope you understand.!

Comment: yes you right but... now tha out put is " 2012/11/26,2012/11/27,2012/11/05  " how do i push this to into a array?using for loop?

Comment: you need to create 'key' for access json value. OR
in your data you receive value as you mention then just write a loop like $.each(data,function(i){array.push(data[i])}. :)